# Do Kenya citizens need a transit visa for Egypt?

Tags: visas, transit, egypt

I'm a Kenyan citizen travelling from Italy to Kenya via Egypt. Do I need a transit visa for Egypt? I will not be leaving the airport.

Comment: Just to be clear, by ‘I will not be leaving the airport’, do you mean ‘I will not leave the international area of the airport’? Will you have to reclaim bags before checking in for your onward flight, for example?

Comment: Which airport in Egypt would you be transiting through?

Comment: @Nate - I'll be transiting through Cairo International Airport

Answer (score 2):

If **all of the following apply you don’t need a transit visa**:

- You are transiting through HBE Alexandria airport
- Your transit time is less than 6 hours
- You don’t leave the transit area to recheck luggage and don’t pass through customs/immigration

If any of the above criteria don’t apply you need a transit visa.

Comment: Given that HBE doesn't have any flights to either Italy or Kenya (per [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borg_El_Arab_Airport#Airlines_and_destinations)), it seems unlikely that OP's itinerary fits these criteria.  Are these criteria necessary as well as sufficient?

Comment: This answer needs a source.  Before the edit, you had a link to the Egyptian consulate.  However, I didn't see anywhere on that page where you are restricted to HBE.

Answer (score 1):

You may not need a transit visa if you will be staying for less than 12 hours and remain at the airport for the duration of your stay.
[Soure: [Egypt Transit Visa Eligibility & Requirements](https://timbu.com/kenya/visa/egypt)]

Answer (score 0):

The answer is not clear.

Entering the OP's data into [Timatic](https://cms.olympicair.com/timatic/webdocsI/spdbmainv.html) returns the following:

> TWOV (Transit Without Visa):
>
> Visa required, except for Passengers transiting through
>   Alexandria (HBE) with a boarding pass for a flight to a third
>   country within 6 hours. They must stay in the international
>   transit area of the airport and have documents required for
>   the next destination.
>
> Visa required, except for Passengers with a confirmed onward
>   ticket for a flight to a third country within 48 hours. They
>   must have documents required for the next destination.
>
> This TWOV facility does not apply when transiting through
>   Alexandria (HBE).

The first paragraph says TWOV is permitted at HBE under the conditions presented in [Daniil's Answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/147849/89966). The third paragraph, however, says TWOV is *not* permitted at HBE. I don't know how to resolve this.

There's more uncertainty further down in the same Timatic report. The following text appears:

> Passport required.
>
> Nationals of Kenya are allowed to enter with an expired
>   passport.
>
> When nationals of Kenya travel with an emergency passport, a
>   national ID card or a temporary passport, it must be valid on arrival.
>
> Passport Exemptions:
>
> - Nationals of Kenya with a national ID card.
> - Nationals of Kenya with a machine-readable temporary passport
>
> VISA NOT REQUIRED.
>
> Minors:
>
> - Passport not required for minors registered in the
>     parent/guardian's passport if traveling with the passport
>     owner.
> - If minor is traveling on a passport of a parent
>     For details, click here
>
> Warning:
>   - Passports and other travel documents accepted for entry are
>     considered valid until the day before the expiration date.

It's not clear if the capitalized words "VISA NOT REQUIRED" apply to the sentences above (in which case a visa for Kenyans is not required), or if the words apply to the sentences below (in which case Minor travelers don't require a separate visa.

The latter interpretation seems more likely, as the report's previous use of capitalized text — such as "TWOV (Transit Without VISA):" at the top of the Timatic report — must necessarily refer to the text that follows, as there's no text preceeding.

I was unable to find a live web link to the Egyptian Embassy in Kenya.

Given Timatic's uncertainty, the OP should inquire directly of his air carrier for the Italy > Egypt leg what documentation will be required to allow boarding. If the OP is risk-averse, he should apply for an Egyptian visa or transit visa.